# R: prediction of stock price by neural-network

Tags: r, neural-network

```
stock<-structure(list(week = c(1L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 
                       1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 3L), close_price = c(774000L, 
                                                                                    852000L, 906000L, 870000L, 1049000L, 941000L, 876000L, 874000L, 
                                                                                    909000L, 966000L, 977000L, 950000L, 990000L, 948000L, 1079000L, 
                                                                                    NA, 913000L, 932000L, 1020000L, 872000L, 916000L), vol = c(669L, 
                                                                                                                                               872L, 3115L, 2693L, 575L, 619L, 646L, 1760L, 419L, 587L, 8922L, 
                                                                                                                                               366L, 764L, 6628L, 1116L, NA, 572L, 592L, 971L, 1181L, 1148L), 
              obv = c(1344430L, 1304600L, 1325188L, 1322764L, 1365797L, 
                      1355525L, 1308385L, 1308738L, 1353999L, 1364475L, 1326557L, 
                      1357572L, 1362492L, 1322403L, 1364273L, NA, 1354571L, 1354804L, 
                      1363256L, 1315441L, 1327927L)), .Names = c("week", "close_price", 
                                                                 "vol", "obv"), row.names = c(16L, 337L, 245L, 277L, 193L, 109L, 
                                                                                              323L, 342L, 106L, 170L, 226L, 133L, 72L, 234L, 208L, 329L, 107L, 
                                                                                              103L, 71L, 284L, 253L), class = "data.frame")
```

This is subset of data I have. I split the data, one for training and the other for testing.

```
obs<- sample(1:21, 21*0.5, replace=F)
tr.Nam<- stock[obs,]; st.Nam<- stock[-obs,]

library(nnet)
Nam_nnet<-nnet(close_price~., data=tr.Nam, size=4, decay=5e-4)
summary(Nam_nnet)
y<-tr.Nam$close_price
p<-predict(Nam_nnet, st.Nam, type="raw")
p
tt<-table(y,p)
summary(tt)
tt
```

By this nnet procedure, I expect "p" to predict close_price. However, the values of "p" are only "1"s or "Na"s.

What should I do to predict the close_price properly, with nnet?

Answer (score 0):

By default, `nnet` uses logistic output units, i.e., tries to predict a binary variable.
You want linear output units.

```
Nam_nnet <- nnet(
  close_price ~ ., 
  data = tr.Nam, 
  size = 4, decay = 5e-4, 
  linout = TRUE
)
p <- predict(Nam_nnet, st.Nam, type="raw")
plot( p, st.Nam$close_price )
```

However, the internal nodes are still logistic 
(and you probably want that, if you are using a neural network in the first place): 
since the values of the variables are very large, the nodes saturate, 
output a constant value, and the optimizer is stuck on a plateau...

Comment: Now "p" has close_price values but the values are same. It does not good when the stock price prediction is always all time same. Please let me know how to make the predicted price differ day by day.

Comment: The easiest is to transform the data: if most of the values are around 0, say between -2 and 2, the problem will disappear.

Comment: after `scale` I have good values of p, thank you. However, I have another problem. `plot( p, st.Nam$close_price )` This does not work. I got message _Error in st.Nam$close_price : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors_